# collect list of data about models description with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I tried to collect data about description of table from sqlalchemy models.

I found some information from official document and below link is what I found:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html

Follow the link told that I can check types and attribute one by one.

Is there having any function to get all do this at once?

or do just I need to for looping to collect all the data?

I tried to test with my models which is

```
class Tutorial(Base):
__tablename__ = "tutorial"
__table_args__ = {"mysql_engine": "InnoDB",
                  "mysql_charset": "utf8",
                  "mysql_collate": "utf8_bin"}

id = Column(TINYINT(4), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
message = Column(VARCHAR(400), nullable=False)
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you need. You can use `Column(VARCHAR(400), nullable=False,info={'description': 'my description here'})` to add a description to your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in metadata obtained from reflection of the database table: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/reflection.html